# how to change the existing bundle id from itunes connect with new bundle identifier from project

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

Changed project name before submitting to AppStore. So that changed bundle identifier too in the project. In iTunes connect it shows old bundle id how do i change it with a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make another AppId (that will reflect your new bundle id) and set it to your provisioning profiles (dev and distr). Then refresh the profiles in xcode and try signing your app with the new profiles.

Answer (score 2):

how you create a new AppID without deleting the existing one?